# CSS code works only in Netbeans and not in webbrowser

Tags: java, css, netbeans, web-applications

I have some webapplications, written in Netbeans, using CSS.
When I run the file from Netbeans, all works fine. However, there seems to 
be a difference when I acces the application from the browser !
this is a simple example :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            #border_top_and_bottom {
                border-top-style: solid; 
                border-top-color: coral;
                border-top-width: 0.5px;
                border-bottom-style:solid;
                border-bottom-color:coral;
                border-bottom-width: 1.5px;
                padding-bottom: 3px;
                padding-top: 3px; 
                width :600px;
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="border_top_and_bottom">TODO write content</div>        
    </body>
</html>​
```

and this is the result, when I acces the application from the web browser (IE):

[image]

as you can see, there is a border-line missing at the top.
This is one of the problems, features like a shadow on the box, or 
creating tekst near a picture are not working eather. 
this is very annoying for other users because I have never the same result !
(I hope my question is clear ?? )

Comment: so ... you use IE and you are surprised it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I have no choice... there are a lot of users for my application, but they all have to use explorer.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using the correct version of IE ... it worked fine on my IE11. the code looks fine

Comment: I know ! that's why I'me surpsised. What difference is there between the application called as http://localhost:8080/...(the aplication started in Netbeans)  and http://my_pc_name:8080//... the same aplication started in Explorer ????